# Using fgets to read a .CSV file

Tags: c, data-structures, csv

I have already googled a lot about this, but I want to know one thing. I have a `.csv` file that I need to read, pass to a `struct` with linked list. The lines of file doesn't have the same size.

I'm thinking use `fgets()` to read each line, and then use `strtok` to get info through "," and pass to `struct`.

I'M USING LINUX.

```
typedef struct nodo
{
 int row1;
 char row2;
 int row3;
 struct nodo *next;
 struct nodo *nant;
}nodo;

nodo* insert_last(nodo* base1, nodo* nv)
{
    if(base1 == NULL)
        base1 =nv;

    base1->next = NULL;
    while(base1->next != NULL)
        base1 = base1->next;
    base1->next = nv;
    nv->nant = base1;
    nv->next = NULL;    
}

nodo* put2memory(nodo *base1)
{
    nodo *nv;
    FILE *fp1=fopen(xxx,"r");
    char *tok;

    while(fgets((buffer, sizeof(buffer),fp1) != NULL))
    { 
        nv = (nodo*) malloc (sizeof(nodo));
        nv->next=NULL;
        tok = strtok(buffer,",");
        nv->row1=tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL,",");
        nv->row2=tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL,",");
        nv->row3=tok;

        insert_last(base1,nv);
    }
    free(nv);
}

int main()
{
    nodo *base1;

    put2memory(base1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm thinking doing like that but i'm returning "my friend" segmentation fault!!

SYNTAX FILE :

123,abc,23 
23,d,444
.
.
.

Comment: In the inser_last) you are using base1 and nv pointers BUT you have declared parameters to the function as x and y!

Comment: Are you able to compile this program?!

Comment: no..my bad..

nodo* insert_last(nodo *base1, nodo* nv)

Comment: The element `row2` can only hold one character; your data file has 3 characters for that field.

Answer (score 2):

`insert_last` doesn't look good to me for the case where `base1` is null.

```
nodo* insert_last(nodo* base1, nodo* nv)
{
    if(base1 == NULL)
        base1 =nv;
```

At minimum I would put `return nv` here.  Without that, what your code does is set `nv->next` to `nv`. (Or rather try to insert `nv` after `base1` which will be set after `nv.)

As a broader point, note that your `insert_last` is O(n) since it must find the end of the list before inserting.  This means inserting N elements is O(N<sup>2</sup>).  A decent linked list implementation will track the tail element in memory and insert in constant time.

**Update:** read the rest of the code. This is also invalid:

```
nodo *base1;

put2memory(base1);
```

`base1` has not been initialized and is a garbage value at this point.  You're trying to use it as pointer.

Here's one suggestion for how to fix it:

- Add `return` statements to `insert_last`.  I suggest returning the head of the list.  Even better would be to store both head and tail and avoid O(N) inserts.
- Change your call to `insert_last` to do something like:

  list_head = insert_last(base1,nv);
- In `main`, you can do something like:

  list_head = put2memory(NULL);

**Update again:** To illustrate O(1) insertion, here's an adjustment of your `put2memory`.  Note that you'd eventually have to call `free()` on every list node.

```
nodo* put2memory()
{
    nodo *head = NULL, *prev = NULL, *nv;
    FILE *fp1=fopen(xxx,"r");
    char *tok;

    while(fgets((buffer, sizeof(buffer),fp1) != NULL))
    { 
        nv = (nodo*) malloc (sizeof(nodo));
        nv->next=NULL;
        tok = strtok(buffer,",");
        nv->row1=tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL,",");
        nv->row2=tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL,",");
        nv->row3=tok;

        if (prev)
           prev = prev->next = nv;
        else
           head = prev = nv;
    }

    return head;
}
```